# How to fetch API with POST method and Authorization Bearer token in javascript?

Tags: javascript

var get = localStorage.getItem("token");
var token = JSON.parse(get);

```
  function myfun(){
    fetch(url,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers:{
        "Authorization":`Bearer + ${token}`
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        city: account_city.value,
        district: account_dis.value,
        state: account_state.value,
      })
    })
    .then((res)=> res.json())
    .then(data=> console.log(data));
  }
```

I try this code. Please help!!!!

Comment: the code looks right, what's the problem? Only problem I see is, token are suppose to be string, why do you need JSON.parse? You should do a console.log(token) to see what is the in your "token".

Comment: please provide an error message or clarify both required and actual behavior

Comment: Show where `myfun()` is being called too. Apart from not knowing where the account variables are coming from, it looks correct. Do you know how to await for the promise to resolve?

Comment: @amankkg The error message is "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` that's a problem with (your?) server code

Answer (score 3):

Try this, your code looks good, the only issue I am seeing is string Interpolation. What is the issue you are facing

```
{
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
```

Comment: ok, I try this but it's still not working. I can't post in my API

Answer (score 1):

If you use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) from ES6, you don't need to add `+` operator to make a concatenation.

So try either : `` "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` ``  or `"Authorization": "Bearer " + token`